# How to invert the entire screen colours using the Windows Magnification API?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-c++

I'm writing a prank application primarily in Java however with a minor share of Visual C++ to assist with access to some native Windows APIs/functions.

How can I use Visual C++ to automatically invert the colours of the entire screen with a function, imitating the way that Windows Magnifier does it, with a function to revert it back to normal using the Windows Magnification API?

I have done intensive online research and have failed to find any code that achieves my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnification API just uses **DSTINVERT** flag:

A test inverting screen colors =>

```
HDC hDC = GetDC(NULL);
RECT rcClient;
GetClientRect(GetDesktopWindow(), &rcClient);
int nWidth = rcClient.right - rcClient.left;
int nHeight = rcClient.bottom - rcClient.top;
HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDC, nWidth, nHeight);
HBITMAP hBmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);
BitBlt(hMemDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, hMemDC, 0, 0, DSTINVERT);
SelectBitmap(hMemDC, hBmOld);
DeleteDC(hMemDC);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hDC);
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add comments on posts, so i'm writing it down here.

You may have missed the following open source project which is called NegativeScreen.
Here it's description

> Description
>
> NegativeScreen's main goal is to support your poor tearful eyes when
>   enjoying the bright white interweb in a dark room. This task is
>   joyfully achieved by inverting the colors of your screen. Unlike the
>   Windows Magnifier, which is also capable of such color inversion,
>   NegativeScreen was specifically designed to be easy and convenient to
>   use. It comes with a minimal graphic interface in the form of a system
>   tray icon with a context menu, but don't worry, this only makes it
>   easier to use!
>
> Features
>
> Invert screen's colors.
>
> ....

So you may want to check it out for reference https://github.com/mlaily/NegativeScreen